# Replacing digits with Noun using hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

My input sentence is:

> ram where are you

After that i will get this parse tree:

```
' 2|TYPE|nx0e-VPadjn-Vnx1 1|RPron|nx-RP-S 0|NOUN|NXN 3|NOUN|NXN ', '1'
```

I want to replace 2 with 'are' 1 with 'where' and ram with 0 .

How should I do this with hash map?

Comment: You assume that readers will understand the format of this "parse tree" you present. I doubt many can. The literal text "ram" does not appear in your "parse tree".

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on lot of assumptions as your question is not clear enough. But I do not have enough rep to comment.

If you use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on input sentence as:

```
String[] words = "ram where are you".split(" ");
// words[0] => ram
// words[1] => where
// words[2] => are
// words[3] => you
```

It appears your parse tree was generated by parsing the input sentence.
Each entry in first section of parse tree corresponds to a word in your input sentence.
First digit in a parse entry seems to correspond to the index of each word in input sentence.

So a parse entry can be broken as: `<word index>|<word category>|<something not clear>`

So, it seems

```
2|TYPE|nx0e-VPadjn-Vnx1 => are
1|RPron|nx-RP-S => where
0|NOUN|NXN => ram
3|NOUN|NXN => you
```

Based on these assumptions its possible to use a hashmap built using parse tree entries.
You will need to put parse entries in to the map using `key = <word index>; value = <parse entry>`.
That can be done by separating parse tree to entries and then retrieving `<word index>` from each entry.

Once that map is built you can process input sentence and parse tree entries as:

```
String[] words = "ram where are you".split(" ");

Map<Integer, String> entriesMap = getEntriesMap(parseTree); // assuming parseTree is just a String

for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String x = entriesMap.get(i).replaceAll("^" + i + "|", words[i]);
}
```

Method to populate map. There are multiple ways to do this.
Use of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes with proper regex is probably the best way.

```
private Map<Integer, String> getEntriesMap(String parseTree) {
    Map<Integer, String> entriesMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    // assuming parseTree format as: '<parse entries separated by spaces>', '1'
    // use String.split() to split the parseTree by single quote (')
    // first element in returning array would contain the <parse entries separated by spaces>
    // use String.split() again on that element with space to separate parse entries
    // for each <entry> in <parse entries>
    //     split <entry> with pipe (|) and use first element in resulting array as the key and <entry> as the value to put in entriesMap

    return entriesMap;
}
```

Can not figure out what `,'1'` at the end of parse tree corresponds to.

Comment: @user2319395 What is giving a null pointer exception? Have you populated the `entriesMap` properly using parse tree? If you haven't populated the `entriesMap`, you will get a null pointer exception when trying to use `entriesMap.get(i).replaceAll()` as `entriesMap.get(i)` returns `null`. I left out `entriesMap` population, which you need to implement.

Comment: how to populate that plz tell me

Comment: @user2319395 I've edited the answer to provide some hints. You need to try that and update the question with what you have done so far. You also need improve the question and provide more details like how you get access to the parse tree, its format if known, etc.

Comment: @user2319395 You can accept the answer if it solves your problem.  However, you need to improve a lot in terms of asking questions. You should have provided additional details in your question. And don't ask the same question twice. Otherwise you will not get good responses from SO.