# Reordering the string value using hashmap

Tags: java

My sentence is `"ram is going to school"` after giving input it will give an parse tree as:

```
2|TYPE| nx0-VPadjn-VPx1 0|NOUN| NXN 1|AUX| Vvx 3|PREP| Pnx 4|NOUN| NXN
```

I want to reorder it to

```
0|NOUN| NXN 1|AUX| Vvx 2|TYPE| nx0-VPadjn-VPx1 3|PREP| Pnx 4|NOUN| NXN
```

I wrote this code. What should I do to make it work?

Please tell me whether it is possible with `HashMap`. If possible then please tell me how?

```
for(int j=1;j<2;j++) //when multiple parsing is to be done then change the limit to ---parsedderived.length
{
    parsedderived[j] = parsedderived[j].replaceAll("\\^|\\(|\\)|\\~|\\.|\"", " ");
    parsedderived[j] = parsedderived[j].replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "");
    parsedderived[j] = parsedderived[j].replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
    parsedderived[j] = parsedderived[j].replaceAll("(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)", "$1-$2@@$3");
    preparedStatement.setString(4, parsedderived[j]);            

    //String[] x=objSentenceStatusImpl.getStrSourceSen().split("");
    String[] derivedsen=parsedderived[j].split(" ");

    //                    for(int k=1;k<derivedsen.length;k++)
    //                    {
    //                       String[] derivedsen1=derivedsen[k].split("");
    //                       System.out.println(derivedsen);
    //                    }

    String[]Senwords=objSentenceStatusImpl.getStrSourceSen().split("\\s+");//original sentence ram is going to school
    Map<Integer, String> entriesMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < Senwords.length; i++) {//for iterration of sen
        parsedderived[j]=parsedderived[j].replaceFirst(" ","");
        parsedderived[j]=parsedderived[j].replaceAll(" ", "##");

        System.out.println(parsedderived[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific order you want to maintain ?

Comment: @Noob UnChained I want to sort on basis of index value 0,1,2,3 which is at start of '|'

Comment: Are there any spaces in that string ?

Comment: @Noob UnChained yes but that space I replaced wwith ## as mentioned in code

Comment: Your parse tree seem change from time to time ;) The one you are showing here, is it parsedderived[j] without any changes, or after applying all those replaceAll() calls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213638/replacing-digits-with-noun-using-hash-map

Answer (score 1):

A `TreeMap<Integer, String>` will sort the keys for you.  Just enter your `Integer, String` pairs, then when you iterate through `treeMap.values()` your strings will be in the order of their keys.

Comment: how to iterate through treemap...how i get that key value??

Comment: [Here is the TreeMap javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html); use `for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : treeMap.entrySet) { Integer key = entry.getKey(); String value = entry.getValue(); }`

Comment: I am not getting it ...please in my code where i need to change??

Comment: My String value is this I want to ordered it

2|TYPE| nx0-VPadjn-VPx1 0|NOUN| NXN 1|AUX| Vvx 3|PREP| Pnx 4|NOUN| NXN

I want to sort it on basis of index value i.e 0,1,2,3 which is starting of |

like this
  0|NOUN| NXN 1|AUX| Vvx 2|TYPE| nx0-VPadjn-VPx1 3|PREP| Pnx 4|NOUN| NXN
what should i do for that?

Comment: `treeMap.put(index, string)` for all indices/strings

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/treemap-java-tutorial-example-program.html